# Issue with file count on Custom object

Tags: apex, controller, custom-field, custom-controller, count

I have an apex class which updates the files count on custom object called **Declined_Policy__c**.

Below is my apex class:

```
public with sharing class Policy_FileCountClass {

    public static void updateAttachmentCountOnDps(List<ContentDocumentLink> DocuLinks) {
        Set<Id> policyids = new Set<Id>();
        for (ContentDocumentLink cdl : DocuLinks) {
            policyids.add(cdl.LinkedEntityId);
        }

        List<Declined_Policy__c> dpsToUpdate = [
            SELECT Id, Attachments__c,
                (SELECT Id FROM ContentDocumentLinks) 
            FROM Declined_Policy__c WHERE Id IN :policyids
        ];
        for (Declined_Policy__c dp : dpsToUpdate) {
            dp.Attachments__c = dp.ContentDocumentLinks.size();
        }
        update dpsToUpdate;
    }

}
```

Now, as per the above logic, i can able to the count in attachments__c field if there is any file attached to the record or if it is deleted. I could able to see the count in these scenarios. But the issue is that, if there is no file attached to the record during the record insertion, the attachments__c field will be blank instead of displaying 0

Is there any way that i can update the above logic to get the attachments__c to display 0 by default if there is no file attached to it. Please suggest.

Comment: You can set the if condition of size, that if size is greater than 0 then update the field with that size otherwise update the field with '0'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a shorthand check to see if the ContentDocumentLinks is null when setting the value:

```
dp.Attachments__c = dp.ContentDocumentLinks == null ? 0 : dp.ContentDocumentLinks.size();
```

Comment: this didnt work. I could still see blank/null value instead of zero.

Comment: Oh I see you're building the policyIds list from received ContentDocumentLinks, which means the dpsToUpdate query will only ever draw data of Declined Policies that already have documents linked, meaning the record that you're testing isn't being included in the update. I don't have much context on your requirements, but you will need to query Declined Policies independently to get records that may or may not have linked documents